# How do I deserialize a rails serialized object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my model I have:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :surveys
    serialize :survey_status, Hash
```

If I do this puts statement I get:

`puts "survey_status is: " + team.survey_status`

`..survey_status is: { intial_survey_complete: false, second_survey_complete: false, third_survey_complete: false, final_survey_complete: false }`

I'm wanting to test against a single value, but when I try: `puts "survey_status is: " + team.survey_status[:intial_survey_complete]`

I get:

`TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

I'm guessing this is not a hash, but maybe a string? Regardless, the end goal is I'm wanting to see if survey_status[:intial_survey_complete] is true or false.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
if team.survey_status[:intial_survey_complete].false?
  #do stuff
```

Comment: It's definetely string

Comment: The column is a string type with a YAML representation of your object. But activerecord should automatically deserialize for you.

Comment: try some introspection. `puts team.survey_status.class.name` and if you get `Hash` (you should), then try `puts team.survey_status.keys` to see if the keys are symbols or strings.

Comment: Good tip Les, I was try just `.class` and was not getting anywhere, but `class.name` confirms its a string? WTH? I thought the whole point of adding `serialize :survey_status, Hash` at the top of the model would give me a Hash???

Comment: Why do you surprise? You apply `+` to string w/o error. Of course it is string

Comment: Look raw value with `rails db` and `SELECT survey_status FROM teams WHERE id = x;` where x is id of your record

Comment: I added to my post above, hopfully its a bit more clear a out what my end goal is. I want to do something like `if team.survey_status[:intial_survey_complete].false?`